# How do I append to a section of an array? [[]]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have an array of arrays, `theMealIngredients = [[]]`

I'm creating a `newMeal` from a current meal and I'm basically copying all checkmarked ingredients into it from the right section and row from a tableview. However, when I use the `append`, it obviously doesn't know which section to go in as the array is multidimensional. It keeps telling me to cast it as an `NSArray` but that isn't what I want to do, I don't think.

The current line I'm using is:

```
newMeal.theMealIngredients.append((selectedMeal!.theMealIngredients[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
```

Comment: First you should get the section from your source. Put that array (array of rows in that section) into the variable. Then append a meal to that variable. And then replace that section in your source, at its proper index.

Comment: If you're only copying selected ingredients, how do you intend the sections to work if nothing from a section is selected? So if something from sections 0, 2, and 3 are selected, should they be in 0, 2, and 3 of the copy, or in 0, 1, and 2? Understanding what these "sections" are and how you're currently looping would likely be helpful here. It's not quite clear why there are sections and how they relate to meals. Is a meal made up of dishes which are made up of ingredients?

Comment: @RobNapier Hi Rob, thanks for the response. So basically each meal gets given ingredients such as Chicken Pasta is meal1.theMealsIngredients = [[chicken],[pasta],[]] and then sections which are [[meat],[carbs]] etc but then there are optional ingredients such as mushrooms, peppers, spinach and I want people to be able to choose these or not so they should stay in the right section of the copy. Sorry I should have been more clear in the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should re-model your data to match its meaning, then extract your tableview from that. That way you can work much more easily on the data without having to fuss with the special needs of displaying the data. From your description, you have a type, `Meal` that has `[Ingredient]`:

```
struct Meal {
    let name: String
    let ingredients: [Ingredient]
}
```

(None of this has been tested; but it should be pretty close to correct. This is all in Swift 3; Swift 2.2 is quite similar.)

`Ingredient` has a name and a kind (meat, carbs, etc):

```
struct Ingredient {
    enum Kind: String {
        case meat
        case carbs
        var name: String { return self.rawValue }
    }
    let kind: Kind
    let name: String
}
```

Now we can think about things in terms of Meals and Ingredients rather than sections and rows. But of course we need sections and rows for table views. No problem. Add them.

```
extension Meal {
    // For your headers (these are sorted by name so they have a consistent order)
    var ingredientSectionKinds: [Ingredient.Kind] {
        return ingredients.map { $0.kind }.sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name})
    }

    // For your rows
    var ingredientSections: [[Ingredient]] {
        return ingredientSectionKinds.map { sectionKind in
            ingredients.filter { $0.kind == sectionKind }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can easily grab an ingredient for any given index path, and we can implement your copying requirement based on index paths:

```
extension Meal {
    init(copyingIngredientsFrom meal: Meal, atIndexPaths indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        let sections = meal.ingredientSections
        self.init(name: meal.name, ingredients: indexPaths.map { sections[$0.section][$0.row] })
    }
}
```

Now we can do everything in one line of calling code in the table view controller:

```
let newMeal = Meal(copyingIngredientsFrom: selectedMeal,
                   atIndexPaths: indexPathsForSelectedRows)
```

We don't have to worry about which section to put each ingredient into for the copy. We just throw all the ingredients into the Meal and let them be sorted out later.

Some of this is code is very inefficient (it recomputes some things many times). That would be a problem if ingredient lists could be long (but they probably aren't), and can be optimized if needed by caching the results or redesigning the internal implementation details of Meal. But starting with a clear data model keeps the code simple and straightforward rather than getting lost in nested arrays in the calling code.

Multi-dimentional arrays are very challenging to use well in Swift because they're not really multi-dimentional. They're just arrays of arrays. That means every row can have a different number of columns, which is a common source of crashing bugs when people run off the ends of a given row.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is absolutely incredible and I can see you put tons of effort into this for me, so I really appreciate it. I'm pretty new so it's extremely comforting to have such a helpful community around. I was just quickly wondering about this last line,  self.init(ingredients: indexPaths.map { sections[$0.section][$0.row] }). I get an error of "Cannot invoke Meal.init with an argument list type of '(ingredients: [Ingredient]])'

Comment: I forgot to pass the name to the init function.

Comment: Sorry please would you patronise me and explain how I would do that? @RobNapier

Comment: Fixed. The new line is: `self.init(name: meal.name, ingredients: indexPaths.map { sections[$0.section][$0.row] })`. When I originally wrote this in a storyboard, I didn't give meals names, but when I copied it into the answer, I added one without adding it to the init.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the issue. I have my Meal as a class because I want it as an NSObject rather than a struct which may be the issue. However, my class is such: class Meal: NSObject {
    

    var mealTitle:String = ""
    var mealID:Int = 0
    var mealImage = UIImage(named:"")
    var ingredients = [Ingredient]()
    

} and my (convenience) initializer is such: self.init(mealTitle: meal.mealTitle, mealID: meal.mealID, mealImage: meal.mealImage, ingredients: indexPaths.map {sections[$0.section][$0.row] })

Comment: You need to write an explicit init method. You set default values for all your properties (which you generally shouldn't do unless those really are valid values, and you definitely shouldn't use `UIImage(named:"")` when you mean nil). Classes don't get an automatic initializer like structs do, but neither would create an initializer if you set default values this way.

Comment: Perfect, yes I've done that and it all works great. Just two quick issues 1. If the section has > 1 ingredient then the section creates itself twice (for 2) or three (for 3 ingredients) and so on. I have printed to the console and can see IngredientSectionKind with more than 1 ingredient does repeat itself. I wonder why this is? 2. Also how do I get the indexPathsForSelectedRows because I want them to be naturally selected and only a click will remove them, or if their assessorytype is not a checkmark then they will not be included. Any help would be much appreciated? @RobNapier

Comment: I actually managed to sort out the 2. point. However, I still have the problem with no.1 where the sections create themselves multiple time. As I said the IngredientSectionKind does repeat the sections if there are more than one ingredient in a section (for a food group).